# Node js(Express framework): not able to print number API from external server to client browser

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am trying to retrieve weather API from external server and when I am console logging particular data of weather API, it's also showing on my command prompt.
But when I am using get method to show that data on browser I am only able send string data like "description": moderate rain and not number data like "temp": 27
it the crash the app.

Node js code:

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const https = require("https");


app.get("/", function(req, res) {



  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=mumbai&appid=d88391210768983e6be06cdd76bdcde3&units=metric";

  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data) {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const temp= weatherData.main.temp;
      const description= weatherData.weather[0].description;
      console.log(temp);
      console.log(description);

      res.send(temp);
    });
  });

});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port: 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ideally return a json.
It can be:

```
res.send({temp: temp, description: description});
```

The `res.send` has to return a string/object/array/buffer.
You could do something like:

```
res.status(200).send(temp)
```

But sending json response is preferable, and you can scale it as well.

Another hack kind of solution is:

```
res.send("" + temp)
```